# How to run a selenium project on a different server without visual studio

Tags: selenium, c#

I have create a selenium test suit on my pc with visual studio.

I can run it by right clicking on test explorer.
Now i need to run the same project on a different pc where it don't have visual studio, only the ms test framework. In side the bin folder i have project DLL.
I can run the same dll using command line on the same pc.

But when I do the same on other server I am getting some errors.
It is looking the old folder structure on other pc.

Comment: what folder structure exactly, whats the error ? maybe you can edit the project, set folder structure for other pc, then build and run those files on server instead

Comment: Results file:  E:\Users\<user>\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TestWithSeleni
um3\TestWithSelenium3\bin\TestResults\<user>_ES-NB-110 2017-01-18 22_11_17.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings

Run has the following issue(s):
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'WebDriver' directly
or indirectly referenced by the test container 'E:\Users\<user>\documents\visual st
udio 2012\Projects\TestWithSelenium3\TestWithSelenium3\bin\testwithselenium3.dll ' was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found and answer :
easiest way. Just add

```
 string value = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

to your code (at the start point of your test method) Add a breakpoint to the newly added code and check what is the path of `value` variable.

continue the test process and after everything get success navigate to the folder of `values` variable.

You might see all the dlls inside the folder. Just copy them and past ware ever you want and execute the project dll using mstest command line tool.

```
set mstestPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"

%mstestpath%\mstest /testcontainer:CodedUITestProject1.dll
```